# GNU GMP large loop limits

Tags: gmp

I want to loop from 2 to n-1 where n can be as big as 10^200 and in each iteration I want to do computation equivalent to log(i), i being iteration variable. Is it possible for this to run on a standard PC using GNU GMP library in feasible time?

Comment: No. Just count how many operations a CPU can do per second, compare to 10^200, and give up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: **NO**

The clock speed of standard PC's is somewhere around 3 GHz nowadays. This is 3×10<sup>9</sup> times per second. Even if the `log(i)` calculation would take only one CPU cycle, 10<sup>200</sup> cycles would take about 1.057×10<sup>183</sup> years, which is beyond what one would usually consider feasible.